# How to get name of the employee while triggering his salary?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
create or replace trigger trg_t3 after  
    insert OR update or delete of salary  on t2 
    for each row  
begin 
   if 
    to_char(systimestamp,'hh24') not between 9 and 17 
   then 
    insert into  t3  values (:new.salary, :old.salary, sysdate);
   else
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('update is not possible  between 9:00 and 17:00');
   end if;        
end; 
/
```

this will  insert old salary ,new salary and the time on table `t3` based on the conditions mentioned in trigger on table `t2`. But i  need the name of the employee whose salary is updated or delete.

if i am updating a salary on `t2` i need to insert the name of the specific employee whose salary i have modified into `t3`. But current method will only insert old salary, new salary and time

here is the code for creating the tables

```
create table t2 ( name varchar(20), salary varchar2(20));
create table t3 (salary_new   varchar2(50), salary_old  varchar2(20), log_date date);

insert all 
into t2 values('hari',2000) 
into t2 values('sam',40000)
into t2 values('ravi',60000)
into t2 values('manoj',8000)
into t2 values('pratheep',10000)
into t2 values('john',3000)
into t2 values('joe',50000)
into t2 values('scott',70000)
select * from dual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger is marked as `after insert or update or delete`. You have to handle all three situations otherwise it will not work correctly, because when inserting we have no `:old` values and when deleting there are no `:new`.

So if you use `:new.name` then `delete` will put null value. If you use `:old.name` then `insert` will not work correctly. Use variable or do it like here:

```
create or replace trigger trg_t3 after
  insert or update or delete of salary on t2 for each row
begin
  if to_char(systimestamp,'hh24') between 9 and 17 then
    dbms_output.put_line ('update is not possible between 9:00 and 17:00');
  else
    if deleting then
      insert into t3 (salary_new, salary_old, name, log_date)
        values (null, :old.salary, :old.name, sysdate);
    elsif inserting then
      insert into t3 (salary_new, salary_old, name, log_date)
        values (:new.salary, null, :new.name, sysdate);
    elsif updating then
      insert into t3 (salary_new, salary_old, name, log_date)
        values (:new.salary, :old.salary, :new.name, sysdate);
    end if;
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do an insert select

```
insert into  t3  
select emp.name, :new.salary, :old.salary, sysdate
from emp where emp.id = :old.id;
```

Comment: above statement will work if i had an id column. but what if i don't have one .. i have posted  the code for the tables

Comment: If your table doesn't have some kind of ID column, your database design has bigger issues that need resolving first

Comment: Shaun's answer is better in this case; but remember this technique can easily be used to bring in data from other tables

Answer (score 1):

first you need a field to insert the name into so create t3 as

```
create table t3 (salary_new   varchar2(50), salary_old  varchar2(20), log_date date, name varchar(20));
```

then in your trigger simply use

```
insert into  t3  values (:new.salary, :old.salary, sysdate, :new.name);
```

you could use either :new.name or :old.name as it is not changing so would be the same value.

Comment: yes it worked ..i didn't know that we can use **:old** and **:new**  on  names . Thanks shaun